# Benefit of additional tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a product page which displays a user's comment, name and rating of the particular product. These values are stored in my data base as such `"Id, name, comment, rating"`

Now I find myself struggling if I want to store comments,name and rating from all product pages into one table as the output would display comments, name and ratings on every page which I don't want.

Am I correct in trying to pursue this one table theory? Or should I just go ahead and make a seperate table for each product page?

Comment: It is best to use seperate tables. Your users won't change, but your products will.

Comment: Your table should include a "product ID" column, which identifies which product the comment was posted on.

Comment: separate tables does seem like the logical thing to me but I don't want to end up confusing myself later on. So is there actually any benefit from keeping just the one table?
Ahh ok @NiettheDarkAbsol. But how can I Identify the product ID? or page ID?

Comment: You need to research data normalization. As Niet the Dark Absol said, you would just add a column for the product id and select the proper comments per product from that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comments can go in a single table, you should however store the identifier of the product, so you can filter the comments. Example:

```
+------------+------------+------+-----------------+
| comment_id | product_id | name |     comment     |
+------------+------------+------+-----------------+
|     1      |     1      | john | Cool product!   |
|     2      |     2      | jack | Don't like this |
|     3      |     1      | jack | Nice!           |
...
```

Now if you want to display all comments for the product with id 1, you would execute this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `product_id` = 1
```

There you go! You have john's comment, and jacks comment which says "Nice!"

Comment: this makes perfect sense! thank's very much. 
Now i've tried to implement this into my own site, I can do everything (i think) except identify the page or product ID...
So far I have 
$insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO commenttable (name,comment,rate,product_id) VALUES ('$currentuser','$comment','$selectrate','$product_id') ");
But what is the $product_id equal to?

Comment: the id of the product they are commenting on from your products table.

Comment: @Fred-ii two things: first of all don't bother yourself with making an edit and only alter such a trivial thing. Furthermore; it should actually be singular, have you ever seen an `ids`, `names` or `comments` column...?

Comment: @user3632789 if you have a product page, and the product is retrieved from another database table, I assume you have an id of some sort as well?

Comment: @giorgio Sorry about that, my mistake. I misread the query/question. I  read the `FROM comments` which threw me off. I will +1 for that, plus the OP agrees too. Cheers

Comment: @giorgio Well so far there is no product! I have a comment/rating system in place on one page which has a few empty divs that need to be filled.This is probably a horrible way of doing things but I only started learning 3 days ago.
So in my case would it be better to identify the actual page as the product_id ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- np ;) and @ OP eventually you'll want to store your products one-by-one in the database, and save information like price, amount in stock, etc. Then every product will have it's own ID, which you will use some way or another to create url's, link comments, orders, etc.